# Professor requiring volunteer work

Tags: graduate-school, united-states, working-time

I am in a US graduate program and our professor has made a requirement that we have to participate in a program called VITA. It is a volunteer tax aid program for low-income individuals. As a volunteer you usually only review W2 and Social Security information. Not enough undergraduate students volunteered so they decided that the graduate students should be required to help. We (the graduate students) volunteered as undergraduate students and it does not benefit our learning.

Because of this requirement, I will now have to make up 8 hours a week AT my real job, which also does taxes, to not have my pay cut. I am a Staff Accountant.

How can I convince my professor to not require this volunteer work?

Comment: You need to discuss this with the Dean or other responsible at the institution.

Comment: Welcome to AC.SE. Please take a look at our [help]. Right now I am not sure what your question is and it seems more like a rant with some unneeded info (W2's and Social Security). Also the title seems to be missing something, but I am not sure what.

Comment: This VITA? https://www.irs.gov/individuals/free-tax-return-preparation-for-you-by-volunteers

Comment: Welcome to Academia, Darin. I rewrote the body to try to make your problem clearer. I don't know if you can see it until it's approved and if people vote to reopen the question.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, your question is this: you are being required to participate in a volunteer program to help people with their taxes.  You feel that this does not benefit your learning, takes an excessive amount of time (8 hours per week), and is experience that you already get in your job (in fact your job is more advanced).  You're looking for suggestions on how to get out of this requirement.  Does that sum it up?  You could edit your question to make it more clear.

Comment: Yes nate. and Yes Daniel that is that VITA.

Comment: Discuss with your professor or higher as to the facts that 1) you have already done this, 2) your work is above that level at your day job.  I had a similar issue with a 4 week "workshop experience course" at Uni - (welding, turning etc but basic) and I wanted to go home and work contracting doing the same and more for money.  Saw the professor in charge, provided proof and was given the credits, my fellow students were **very** jealous... :)

Comment: what would happen if you just refused?

Comment: To add to @guest’s question, can you clarify how it was communicated to you that you are “required” to participate? Were there any threats, explicit or implied, about what would happen if you refuse? And what is your relationship with this “our professor”? Are they your adviser, or teaching a class you’re in, etc? What sort of power do they hold over you?

Answer (score 1):

If you are self funded through your regular job and need that income, then it is certainly burdensome. It seems that doing what everyone else in the program does doesn't give you any benefit at all. The university has made a commitment to help people, which is a good thing, but have no right to force that commitment on others.

But, perhaps there is an opportunity in this. The volunteers will need supervision and probably need tax advice themselves. You are probably in a good position to do either or both of these, and to do it effectively in less than eight hours per week. You could, for example, use email to field questions from volunteers as they arise, making the others more efficient and effective.

If this hasn't been resolved properly otherwise, you might suggest that as an option. Supervision might give you some experience that would be valuable later, depending on your regular job requirements.